# Radio Button change / click not working

Tags: jquery, html

Dynamically loaded via AJAX

here is the head section

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/main.css">
     <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</head>
```

```js
$('.vp_names').on("change", "input[name='vp_names']", function(event) {
  alert('got here'); // NEVER FIRES  
})
```

```html
<div class='vp_names'>
  <input id="vp_names_1" checked name='vp_names' value='1' type='radio'/>
  <label class="drinkcard-cc label_card male" for="vp_names_1">George</label>
  <input id="vp_names_2" name='vp_names' value='2' type='radio'/>
  <label class="drinkcard-cc label_card male" for="vp_names_2">Jungle</label>
</div>
```

Variations of the above code work for all my other inputs / buttons on the same page / load.  Range inputs work, other radio / checkboxes work.  I've tried change / click.  I've tried with :radio and without.  I've tried changing the names, changing the selector, changing the parent selector, nothing will get the radio buttons to fire.

** Update **

while not figuring out why it was not working, as it works this way in other sections of the code, changing it to the following did work.  So if you are having a similar issue, try this.

```
$('#view_profile').on("change", ".vp_names", function(event) {
    alert('got here');
}
```

and

```
<input class='vp_names' id="vp_names_1" checked name='vp_names' value='1' type='radio'/>
<label class="drinkcard-cc label_card male" for="vp_names_1">John</label>

Removed class from parent div
```

I still use the 'bag' of the view_profile, and this is the method for attaching to dynamically loaded content via ajax.

** Solution **

Appears to have been a JS cache issue as suggested by Rob.

Comment: Any errors? You have jQuery on the page?

Comment: `$ is not defined` means that you have no jQuery on the page.

Comment: no errors, everything is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your selector is the problem. I'm not even sure if input[name=...] is valid (not that my ignorance is proof that it isn't valid).

Give all the inputs you want to be affected the same class, and then just trigger from the class.

```
<input type="radio" class="vp_radio" ... /> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.vp_radio').on('change', function(){ 
        //logic
     });
 });
```

Comment: I use this selector for the ranges, buttons, and checkboxes without issue.  but, I don't know everything, could be doing something wrong, which is why i posted this.  I did try to give them all a class and it still did not work.  It's very strange because I have additional code that is identical, except the names / location in the same loaded page, that works.

Comment: Does anything log in your console? It seems strange that this element simply wouldn't fire without also firing an issue somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure why, by I just went in to try again (good ole sanity check) - use the same style but changed to class on the radios, and now its firing.  no idea why it works for some and not others, but at least it's working now!

Comment: Is the script inside your html files, or is it included as a library? If you're including it instead of writing the script inline, you probably just needed to break the cache. Glad it's working! And thanks for teaching me something about input selectors!

Comment: it's linked in the header.  I'll switch back now and see if it works both ways.  didn't think about cache, but that could be.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("body").on("click","input[name='vp_names']" ,function(event) {
    alert('got here'); // FIRES
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='vp_names'>
  <input id="vp_names_1" checked name='vp_names' value='1' type='radio'/>
  <label class="drinkcard-cc label_card male" for="vp_names_1">George</label>
  <input id="vp_names_2" name='vp_names' value='2' type='radio'/>
  <label class="drinkcard-cc label_card male" for="vp_names_2">Jungle</label>
</div>
```

Comment: did you load that in with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are not including the jquery script. Your code snippet has no jQuery in it. Add this to the html page:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`